# Can't install package found on packages.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt, software-installation, libraries

I'm trying to install [xcb-util-wm](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/xcb-util-wm), but keep getting `E: Unable to locate package xcb-util-wm`, anybody know why this is?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5

Thanks!

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update` yet at least once?

Comment: Yes, multiple times

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, turns out it's a source package, not a binary package, installed it by downloading tarball and manually building/installing it.

Comment: Maybe it would have been included in another package that starts with `xcb`? This method of installation may come back to haunt you if dependences are later updated. Best to use software center or `apt` to manage the software on your system. (I would not use packages.ubuntu.com for anything but research or as an absolutely last resort to obtain a package)